# SONAR - database quality

Tags: sql, sonarqube

I have recently implemented Continuous Integration for SQL Server using SSDT, Jenkins and Perforce.

This has proven to be a revelation to our firm, and our turn around time for database changes is now extremely fast.  The DBA Team are on board with this new methodology, as their number of support issues have dramatically dropped.

I have implemented a database build server, that is an empty shell, each time a database change is checked into to perforce the whole database is deployed to this shell.  Thus any breaking dependencies are picked up.

We use SONAR to report the quality of code for C# and Java.  I would like to extend this not only to T-SQL but also generically to database platforms that have a supported JDBC driver.

To make the database review generic, and also allow the DBA Team to write the rules, I would like to write a plugin that will run SQL scripts (each a rule) against a database, and then report the results.

The idea is that a DBA Team could write a suite of scripts (rules) that will give them confidence in the data model.  Examples include

- list all tables that do not have a primary key
- list all tables that do not have a unique index
- list all tables that are not referenced by a foreign key constraint
- list all roles that are not used

Ideas would be appreciated.

Dave.

Comment: Sounds like a good plugin to develop. Not sure what feedback you're looking for here. Implementing the cookbook in java would be a great idea as it would be simpler to integrate into ANT and/or Maven builds scripts.

Comment: Mark, thanks for the positive feedback.  The problem is that I don't know where to start with writing a plugin.  The sonar documentation details how to build rules, but each rule will be run against each file in the project, which in this case is not needed.